# Can't access webpage using Internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-401

I have a problem accessing an intranet website with IE8. I can access the site through Firefox or any other browser, except IE. IE will prompt for a username and password but never accepts the credentials and just shows a 401 message, "You are not authorized to view this page"

The website is configured as follows:

Windows Server 2003

IIS Directory Security > Authentication Methods > "Integrated Windows authentication" only

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to run the site locally? Or is it hosted on some other server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an IE security setting.  I'd check two things in options:

1. In the Advanced tab, in the security section, is Enable Integrated Windows Authentication checked?
2. In the Security tab, does the site come up under the Local Intranet zone?  If not, add it.  Also, make sure the User Authentication item under custom settings is set to one of the Automatic Logon options (checking Automatic Logon with current user name and password should make the browser automatically log into the site).

Comment: the site wasn't part of the local intranet zone, thanks you hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start when troubleshooting 401 errors in IIS is this Microsoft [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/907273)